# How to Send Data to the Main Activity from a Foreground Service in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, foreground-service, linphone, startforegroundservice

I am currently using the Linphone library to handle call functionality in my Android app. I have implemented a foreground service that initializes the Linphone's code, core, and listener. The goal is to notify the main activity when there is an incoming or connected call.

I am looking for a way to send data from the foreground service to the main activity to trigger these notifications. Can I use an interface in the foreground service to achieve this? If yes, how can I implement it?

I have already researched various solutions and came across the idea of using a bound service, but I'm unsure if it's the correct approach for my situation. My requirement is to keep the service running in the background even when the user closes the app, and I also want to display a notification to the user.

For more context, I start the foreground service and show a notification when the user clicks on 'enter call queue.' Similarly, when the user clicks on 'exit queue,' I stop the service and remove the notification.

Additionally, I understand that I could implement the listener directly in the main activity to handle these events, but for now, I want to use the listener exclusively within the service.

Any guidance on the best approach to achieve this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried these solutions:

1. Create Static Variables and Methods: While this solution may be straightforward, it is not considered optimal due to potential issues with global state management and memory leaks.
2. Create a Bound Service (Best for Two-way Communication):I still have some doubts about this approach and its impact on keeping the service running in the background.
3. Use Intent to Send Data to Service:it may not be optimal in scenarios where frequent updates are required, such as sending data every 5 seconds.
4. Use Broadcast Receiver:they are not reliable for frequent and high-volume communication needs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.